# Understanding the definition of Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, definition, sylow-theory, p-groups, maximal-subgroup

Here is the definition of Sylow $p$-group (source: wikipedia)

> For a prime number $p$, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a group $G$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$, *i.e.* a subgroup of $G$ that is a $p$-group (so that the order of every group element is a power of $p$) that is not a proper subgroup of any other $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Also here is the definition of a maximal subgroup (source: wikipedia)

> In group theory, a maximal subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is a proper subgroup, such that no proper subgroup $K$ contains $H$ strictly.

So, in accordance with the definition of maximal subgroup, a maximal $p$-subgroup $H$ should be a proper $p$-subgroup of the group $G$ such that no other proper $p$-subgroup $K$ contains $H$ strictly.

But the definition of Sylow $p$-subgroup does not say that it is a proper subgroup of the group $G$. According to its definition, if say, $G$ is a group of order $2^3$, then the Sylow $p$-subgroup is the group itself, but if I follow the definition as given by me, the Sylow $p$-subgroup should be a proper subgroup of $G$ *i.e.* a subgroup of order $2^2$.

I know I am misunderstanding the definition somewhere. Please help me rectify myself.

Comment: The ambiguity is merely a semantic one and only makes a difference in the exceptional case that $G$ is itself a $p$-group. I would argue that, in that case, the Sylow $p$-subgroup should be $G$ itself since otherwise the usual Sylow theorems would fail to hold in this exceptional case. (Think of the group $C_2 \times C_2$.)

Comment: If a group is a p-group, then it has itself as the only Sylow-p-subgroup.

Comment: @Jeroen That means the definition given by me is correct only  with the exception when G is itself a p-group?

Comment: I'd say that it is morally correct always. But you are right that you'd have to consider the word 'maximal' in a loose rather than a technical sense.

Comment: Why would you expect a maximal $p$-subgroup to be a maximal subgroup?

Comment: @Derek I was just trying to get the meaning of maximal in the definition.

Comment: The real issue, in my opinion, is that what we call "maximal subgroup" should be called "maximal **proper** subgroup." In general, we talk about "maximal X subgroup" to mean a subgroup that is maximal (under the partial order afforded by inclusion) among all subgroups with propery X. So "maximal normal subgroup", "maximal $p$-subgroup", "maximal core-free subgroup", etc. But through laziness/custom we say "maximal subgroup" when we mean "maximal *proper* subgroup".

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in comments, I think the issue here is actually that we misname "maximal subgroup".

Of course, given a partially ordered set $P$, a *maximal element* (or $P$) is an element $p\in P$ with the property that for all $x\in P$, if $p\leq x$ then $p=x$.

If we have a class $\mathfrak{X}$ of subgroups, partially ordered by inclusion, we often talk about "maximal $\mathfrak{X}$-subgroups" (also "minimal $\mathfrak{X}$-groups", though that is less common). Thus, "maximal $p$-subgroup" means "maximal among the $p$-subgroups".

We say "maximal subgroup" (and "maximal normal subgroup"), but we *really* mean "maximal **proper** subgroup" (that is, the class $\mathfrak{X}$ is the class of *proper* subgroups, not the class of all subgroups). (And we likewise really  mean "maximal *proper* normal subgroup").

So we should say:

> A *maximal proper subgroup* of $G$ is a proper subgroup $H$ of $G$ that is not properly contained in any proper subgroup of $G$.

If we used that terminology and definition, you would likely have no problems. But it is an unfortunate fact that nobody says "maximal proper subgroup", we just say "maximal subgroup" and elide the "proper" clause, on the (flimsy) excuse that *of course* we must mean proper subgroup, as otherwise the concept would just be "the group $G$" and it would be silly to introduce such a nomenclature for the whole  group.

Comment: So maximal p-subgroup should be a proper subgroup but for p-groups, maximal p-subgroup is the group itself. Why such contradiction?

Comment: @Esha: No, a maximal p-subgroup is maximal among all p-subgroups. In a p-group, it is the whole group because the whole group is a p-subgroup of itself and is maximum among p-subgroups, so it is the unique maximal p-subgroup.

Comment: @Esha: It's not "maximal *proper* p-subgroup", this one is "maximal p-subgroup". The only ones where we are eliding "proper" is in "maximal [proper]subgroup" and in "maximal [proper] normal subgroup".

Comment: Okay...so here maximal p subgroup does not have to be proper. Here maximal does not carry any hidden 'proper'

Comment: @Esha As I said, generally the only misnamed one is "maximal subgroup" and "maximal normal subgroup".